# jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect: 0.0.0.0<00>/192.168.43.103 jcifs.util.transport.TransportException java.net.SocketException

Tags: java, sockets, samba, smb

I am getting this error when i tried to read `smb` files.

PS

```
C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName SMB1Protocol


FeatureName      : SMB1Protocol 

DisplayName      : SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support

Description      : Support for the SMB 1.0/CIFS file sharing protocol, and the 

Computer Browser protocol.

RestartRequired  : Possible

State            : Enabled

CustomProperties :
                   ServerComponent\Description : Support for the SMB 1.0/CIFS 
file sharing protocol, and the Computer Browser protocol. ServerComponent\DisplayName : SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support
                   ServerComponent\Id : 487
                   ServerComponent\Type : Feature
                   ServerComponent\UniqueName : FS-SMB1
                   ServerComponent\Deploys\Update\Name : SMB1Protocol
```

It is saying my `smb1` is enabled but I am still getting this error.

```
package shared_folder;

import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication;
import jcifs.smb.SmbException;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "smb://192.168.43.103/shared/";
        String userName = "shyam";
        String password = "shyam";
        String domain = null;
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, userName, password);
        try {
            doRecursiveLookup(new SmbFile(url, auth));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /*
    * Recursively scans through the folder for files and prints the name of folder and file
    */
    public static void doRecursiveLookup(SmbFile smb) {
        try {
            if (smb.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(smb.getName());
                for (SmbFile f : smb.listFiles()) {
                    if (f.isDirectory()) {
                        doRecursiveLookup(f);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("\t:" + f.getName());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("\t:" + smb.getName());
            }
        } catch (SmbException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 10 you need to use and enable SMB2! (and optionally disable SMB1)

Possible solution:
[SmbException failed to connect hostname/IP_address throwing with proper credentials in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68529198/smbexception-failed-to-connect-hostname-ip-address-throwing-with-proper-credenti/68541028#68541028)